# Specific Info from XML Document

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to parse XML data and having a hard time doing it.  Here is the XML part

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"> <GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult ASIN="b0091raue4" status="Success">   <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>   <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>b0091raue4</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
    </Identifiers>
    <LowestOfferListings>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>98-100%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>7</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>723</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>28.70</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>28.70</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>0.00</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
      <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>27</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>29.00</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>29.00</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>0.00</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>


     <LowestOfferListing>
        <Qualifiers>
          <ItemCondition>Collectible</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubcondition>Mint</ItemSubcondition>
          <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
          <ShippingTime>
            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
          </ShippingTime>
          <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>98-100%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
        </Qualifiers>
        <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
        <SellerFeedbackCount>1138</SellerFeedbackCount>
        <Price>
          <LandedPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>129.99</Amount>
          </LandedPrice>
          <ListingPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>125.00</Amount>
          </ListingPrice>
          <Shipping>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>4.99</Amount>
          </Shipping>
        </Price>
        <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
      </LowestOfferListing>
    </LowestOfferListings>
  </Product>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>ba623b4e-338b-4bc7-9ee0-9fd2e20489d3</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse>
```

I want to loop through all of the "LowestOfferListing" nodes just return the "ItemCondition" and "Amount".

I have tried putting the data into an XML document, dataset, and datatable.  Here is where i am at:

```
        Dim xml As New Xml.XmlDocument()
        xml.LoadXml(responseBody)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.ReadXml(New StringReader(responseBody))
```

Does anyone know how to loop through and retireve just these two values?

Comment: This also doesn't work: 
            For Each row In ds.Tables("LowestOfferListing").Rows
                MsgBox(row.item("Qualifiers/ItemCondition").ToString)
            Next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) offers a nice API for querying XML, especially in VB.NET with XML literal support.  e.g. This will show the ItemCondition and Amount (from ListingPrice) fields.

**Update** You will need the XML namespace import added below to get things to work.

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Linq
' Import the XML namespace for the elements being queried
Imports <xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
'...
Dim xml = XElement.Parse(responseBody)
Dim result =
    From item In xml...<LowestOfferListing>
    Select
        Condition = item.<Qualifiers>.<ItemCondition>.Value,
        Amount = item.<Price>.<ListingPrice>.<Amount>.Value
For Each item In result
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Condition, item.Amount)
Next
```

Comment: Do i leave the "..." before the "<LowestOfferListing>"?

Comment: That doesn't work either.  No data.  I know i have data because i can put the data into a dataset and see it (ds.ReadXml(New StringReader(responseBody))

Comment: I believe that the issue is probably related to the namespaces, which I cut out when building the code, since your sample data was incomplete.  Give me a few minutes to adjust.

Comment: 10-4.  I posted the end of the xml.

Comment: You should just need the `Imports <xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">` line added above.

Comment: absolutely perfect.  Just out of curiosity, why would i have to do that?  Why wouldn't i put that in the "xml...<LowestOfferListing>" part?

Comment: can i do without an import statement?

Comment: The `Import` allows LINQ to XML to fully-qualify the element names in the query, since, for example, `<Price>` in two different namespaces is not the same element.  I don't know of a way to specify the namespace in the query, so I always use the `Import`, but maybe I've just not found that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should use XPath for this:

```
Dim xpathDoc As XPathDocument
Dim xmlNav As XPathNavigator
Dim xmlNI As XPathNodeIterator
xpathDoc = New XPathDocument("c:\builder.xml")
xmlNav = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator()
xmlNI = xmlNav.Select("/LowestOfferListings/LowestOfferListing/Qualifiers/ItemCondition")
While (xmlNI.MoveNext())
  System.Console.WriteLine(xmlNI.Current.Name + " : " + xmlNI.Current.Value)
End While
```

The xpath should match the nesting of the element you are interested in the xml.

Comment: Thanks Jerome - but i'm not getting any data.  It goes straight from "While" to "End While".  Could the path be wrong?

Comment: see the revised code. you need to match the xpath express according to the nesting of the xml element you want to retrieve

Comment: swapped /LowestOfferListings/ItemCondition/Qualifiers to /LowestOfferListings/Qualifiers/ItemCondition

Comment: No - no data.  I know that the xpathDoc has data because i see it.  The xmlNI just isn't selecting it.

Comment: Try using '/LowestOfferListings/LowestOfferListing/Qualifiers/ItemCondition'. I think I mistyped the xpath again.